# How can group row in ngx datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

i have a problem, i must group rows per tipoProyecto row,
but in the documentation appear with columns in template
https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#row-grouping

I have columns defined on typescript, no in template.

```
this.columns = [
  { $$id: 'proyecto.codigo', prop: 'proyecto.codigo', name: 'Proyecto', cellTemplate: this.selectTemplate },
  { $$id: 'actividad.id', prop: 'actividad.nombre', name: 'Actividad', cellTemplate: this.actividadTemplate },
  { prop: 'proyecto.tipoProyecto.nombre', name: 'Tipo Proyecto' },
  { $$id: 'detalle.id', prop: 'detalle.nombre', name: 'Detalle', cellTemplate: this.detalleTemplate },
  { prop: 'master', name: 'MASTER', cellTemplate: this.masterTemplate },
  { $$id: 'tipoHora.id', prop: 'tipoHora.nombre', name: 'Tipo Hora', cellTemplate: this.tipohoraTemplate },
  { prop: 'lunes', name: 'Lunes', cellTemplate: this.inputTemplate, summaryFunc: (cells) => this.sumaLunes(cells) },
  {
    prop: 'martes',
    name: 'Martes',
    cellTemplate: this.inputTemplate,
    summaryFunc: (cells) => this.sumaMartes(cells),
  },
  {
    prop: 'miercoles',
    name: 'Miercoles',
    cellTemplate: this.inputTemplate,
    summaryFunc: (cells) => this.sumaMiercoles(cells),
  },
  {
    prop: 'jueves',
    name: 'Jueves',
    cellTemplate: this.inputTemplate,
    summaryFunc: (cells) => this.sumaJueves(cells),
  },
  {
    prop: 'viernes',
    name: 'Viernes',
    cellTemplate: this.inputTemplate,
    summaryFunc: (cells) => this.sumaViernes(cells),
  },
  { prop: 'eliminar', name: 'Eliminar', cellTemplate: this.checkboxTemplate },
];
```

In the documentation the columns are defined in template.
I must use this method.
I need to group rows according to their project type